# jquery select all elements in just the current element and not child element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've done a few things such as selecting all children of an element, all parents of an element, first child etc.. but this is a little tricky.

I have the structure somewhat similar to this:

```
<div class="body">
    <a href="something">Something</a>
    <small>
          <a href="something-else">Something-else</a>
    </small>
</div>
```

and this structure is repeated a whole lotta times.

I need to select all `<a>` elements found only in the top level `div.body` and ignore all `<a>` that's found in the `<small>` element.

How do I go around with this please?

thanks,.

Comment: *selecting all children* ... that's what you have to do. Children are only the immediate descendants of a node (just like in real life).

Comment: @Felix, nope, I don't want to select all children, just the first level ones

Comment: That's a problem of using the correct terminology then: As I said, by definition *children* are only the immediate descendants (I mean of course you still have to filter the children for `a` nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the child selector:

```
$("div.body > a")
```

`A > B` means: "B is a immediate child of A", whereas
`A B` means: `B is a (not strictly immediate) child of A.

Comment: Oh, awesome, I did not know this, thanks you so much. You also explained what the syntax means.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the [`child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) rather than the [`descendant` selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

```
$('div.body > a');
```

Answer (score 2):

The [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) only selection **direct** elements of a parent element, so:

`$('div.body > a')`

should do the trick